# Contiki-SNMP for v 2.6?

Tags: contiki

I am working with TelosB motes and need to implement SNMP using contiki. I found ContikiSNMP at https://github.com/sehgalanuj/contiki-snmp/

It is listed as 2.5 and it is not working with COntiki-2.6. I tried simulating the example programs in the ContikiSNMP folder using Cooja. But I am encountering errors. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue, but I can compile with minimal-net motes as example, I am trying compile using sky motes as show below:

```
./../core/dev/sht11.c:242:3: error: ‘P1DIR’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../../core/dev/sht11.c: In function ‘scmd’:
../../core/dev/sht11.c:266:9: error: ‘P1IN’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../../core/dev/sht11.c:288:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘clock_wait’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
make[1]: *** [obj_sky/sht11.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/contiki-snmp/examples/snmpd-sky'
make: *** [all] Error 2
user@instant-contiki:~/contiki-snmp/examples/snmpd-sky$
```

I use contiki 2.7

Thanks,